# LotusScript - How to create button to change values in certain fields and refresh form?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Currently reworking an old form in LotusNotes where if user edits the form certain fields will be reset to blank. Now I need to place that function into a button so that users can simply edit without the need to reset those fields, but still allow them to use the reset function if needed.

What I basically did was copy the LotusScript code in the Form portion which enables this function and paste it into a button action:

```
------------------------------------------------
Reset Approval (Action) : (Declaration)
------------------------------------------------

Dim editflag as string

------------------------------------------------
Reset Approval (Action) : Click
------------------------------------------------

Sub Click(Source As button)

Dim w As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set uidoc = w.CurrentDocument

 ' Get value for Approver 1 and 2

Approver_1 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Approver_1" )
Approver_2 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Approver_2" )
status1 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "status1" )
status2 = uidoc.FieldGetText( "status2" )
author = uidoc.FieldGetText( "Author" )
submit = uidoc.FieldGetText( "submit" ) 
cname = session.CommonUserName & "/ASY/MAWA"
aname = session.UserName

'Msgbox submit
'Cannot edit if user is not the author or approver 1 and 2
If (aname <> author And cname <> Approver_1  And  cname <> Approver_2) Then
    Msgbox "You Dont Have The Authorization To Edit This Document", 16, "Access Restricted"
    Continue = False
    Exit Sub
End If  

 '''''''''''''If user is the author prompt warning if the form already approved
If (aname = author And (status1 = "Yes" Or status2 = "Yes")) Then
    Message = "Editing This Document Will Reset The Approval Status" & Chr$(13) &_ 
    "Do you wish to continue?"  
    YesNo = Messagebox(Message,36,"Continue?")
    If YesNo = 7 Then 
        continue = False
        Exit Sub
    Else
        editflag = "Y"
    End If
End If  

Dim doc1 As NotesDocument
Dim source1 As NotesUIDocument
'Use backend notes object to assign value to current document
Set doc1 = source1.Document

'Check if document in edit mode
If (source1.EditMode = True) Then
    'If edit flag is "Y" then reset status1 and status2 value
    If (editflag = "Y") Then            
        doc1.ReplaceItemValue "status1", ""
        doc1.ReplaceItemValue "status2" ,""
        doc1.ReplaceItemValue "submit" ,"progress"
    End If
End If
'Refresh document to anable send button
Call source1.Refresh    

End Sub
```

When I save the changes I didn't get any error messages so I assumed it's OK. But when I try to test it I get an `Object Variable is not set` error and the form doesn't change. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: NEVER write even one line of LotusScript without error handler. Put these lines around your code:

```
On error goto ErrorHandler

...your code... 

EndOfRoutine:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  Msgbox err+"-"+error+" in line "+erl
  Resume EndOfRoutine
```

Then you will find that the error occurs in the line

```
Set doc1 = source1.document
```

As you never set uidoc1 but only uidoc.

Change it to

```
Set doc1 = uidoc.Document
```

and replace all other instances of source1 with uidoc (you can remove the Dim source1 as NotesUiDocument line) then it will work.

Comment: I tried adding ErrorHandler as you suggested but I get an error when I try to save `Reset_Approval: Click: 66: type mismatch`. Error appears on `Msgbox err+"-"+error+" in line "+erl`

Comment: Then use & instead of +: msgbox err & "-" & error & " in line " & erl

Comment: Ok ErrorHandler is set and I tried changing source1 with source but not I get error in line `If (source.EditMode = True) Then`. Error message is `Not a member: EDITMODE`

Comment: Replace source with uidoc, that will help

Comment: ok Done that and I get same message for line 60 `Call source.Refresh`. So I change source with uidoc as well. Only for it to show ANOTHER error on the same line when I try to live test it: `4407-Document command is not available. in line 60`

Comment: Refresh is only available in Edit- Mode. You need to move the command inside the "If (uidoc.EditMode = True) Then"- structure.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks.